Relay module I/O pins resistor
I'm making a project with a 12v relay module and a AC motor. The circuit is simple and doesn't need any microcontrollers. I want to control the motor using a relay and a float switch. I was hoping can I use the Trigger Input with the VCC pin since the switch basically turn on the motor when the float switch is closed. I know that the relay module triggers with the logic input so it should be under 5v and around under a 20mA. I saw that the module uses a optocoupler so I thought that can I use a resistor to drop down 12v to under 5v with a 330 ohm since optocoupler has a IR LED inside so I can just limit current with the resistor.

But then I got a circuit of the module and it looks like a 10k resistor (103 SMD) in series with the IR LED of optocoupler (LTV-354T)

So do I need a 330 ohm resistor since the relay module already have a 10k resistor in series with the optocoupler? Can I just connect the trigger input to control the relay without any current limiting resistor?

what does the datasheet say?

Says Forward current 50mA, Power dissipation 70mW, Forward voltage 1.2V, Terminal Capacitance 30pF.

that's what it says in the relay module datasheet? ... please add a link to the datasheet

LTV-354T Lite-On
